# Ant jar file for swing program

Tags: ant

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="javaGui" default="execute">

<target name="init" depends="clean">
   <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
   <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" />
</target>    
<target name="execute" depends="compile">
   <java classname="Swing" classpath="build/classes" />
   <jar destfile="dist/final.jar" basedir="build/classes" />
</target> 
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build" />
     <delete dir="dist" />
</target>
```

This is ant script to generate jar file.problem is those code will generate jar but when i click on that jar it is not opening  means it not showing any GUI.

im new to this please let me know what is going wrong.

javaGUI is project and Swing is class name

Answer (score 0):

jar file will not open in GUI. You need to run jar file from console.
Go to dist directory -> run this command:

```
$ java -jar final.jar [optional parameters]
```

For more details : see this [reference](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/running-an-executable-jar-from-command-line/)

**UPDATE**

Instead of giving ant from target execute, try this :

```
 <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Swing"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
 </target>

  <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
  </target>
```

Comment: on command prompt you are seeing this error ? if yes, make sure that you are in the same dir as in which jar file exist.

Comment: Actually it is showing message Failed to load main-class manifast attribute from

Comment: Then it is the problem in your project. Compile and run it separately first in IDE.

Comment: 1)[apache](http://ant.apache.org)

2)[vannila](http://www.vaannila.com/ant/ant-tutorial/ant-tutorial.html/)

And accept this answer if you are satisfied..!!